# .Net library to handle spatial data from SQL Server

Tags: .net, sql-server, geospatial

I want to create application which would display spatial data on Map. I'm thinking about using SQL Server spatial features but not sure how should I handle that data in C#. Is there a good library I could use for that?

Comment: belive it or not I spent 20 minutes answering this with a code example, and SO crashed and wouldn't let me submit or copy the text I'd entered. Sorry about that...

Comment: So sad. I hope you will recover from the shock and give it a one more try :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a good library I could use
>   for that?

What is the "that" specifically? What you mean handling spatial data? Process, performing geometry computational operations or just displaying?

If you mean working with geometries and performing operations on geometries, you may try to use SqlGeometry and related types available for .NET in [Microsoft.SqlServer.Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.types%28SQL.105%29.aspx) namespace

Speaking of ORM, you may try to use frameworks available for .NET like [NHibernate](http://www.developer.com/open/article.php/3709346/Using-NHibernate-as-an-ORM-Solution-for-NET.htm)